# iOS MDM Device Information payload results

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mdm

I'm working over iOS MDM and found some inconsistencies with the response of the DeviceInformation payload. See response below based on test performed on iPhone (iOS 6) and iPad (iOS 5). The response received in all tests return different (dubious in some cases) data.

Need help understanding the data.

---

**iPhone**:
[image]

- The *Subscriber Carrier Network* is *"Carrier"* but I expect it to be *"Reliance"*
- *Current Carrier Network* is empty
- *Phone Number* is empty except for one operator
- No details available for *Tata* operator

---

**iPad**:
[image]

- Unlike iPhone, *Current Carrier Network* for all operators is available
- *Subscriber Carrier Network* is *"Carrier"* for all operators except the last one.
- *Phone Number* is empty except for one operator

---

**iPad (on WiFi after removing SIM)**:
[image]

- *Subscriber Carrier Network* should be empty
- *Phone Number* should be empty
- *Is Roaming* should be false
- *Subscriber MCC* should be empty
- *Subscriber MNC* should be empty
- *Current MCC* should be empty
- *Current MNC* should be empty

---